# Error occurs while displaying Data in View asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get  windows event logs and display in a html page. I am using asp.net MVC 5 for this but facing this issue. Kindly help me out I will be very thankful to you.

---

Please see the link for error

---

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9OJt.png)

---

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[WebApplication1.Models.Eventlogg]'.

here is my code

### controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string eventLogName = "Application";
    string sourceName = "EventLoggingApp";
    string machineName = "nb-ahja1";
    EventLog eventLog;
    eventLog = new EventLog();
    eventLog.Log = eventLogName;
    eventLog.Source = sourceName;
    eventLog.MachineName = machineName;
    var model = new List<object>();
    foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
    {
        model.Add(log.Source);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

### Model

```
public class Eventlogg
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Eventlogg>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Source
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Change `var model = new List<object>();` to `var model = new List<EventLogEntry>();`